# tomcat https cause request.getParameter return null

Tags: java, tomcat, https

testing server uses centos 7 and tomcat 9

originally, testing server tomcat use `http`, this tomcat contains 4 web apps: `a.war`, `b.war`, `c.war` and `d.war`, it works fine and its `server.xml` looks like:

```
<Connector  
        port="80"
        protocol="HTTP/1.1"  
        connectionTimeout="60000" 
        keepAliveTimeout="15000"
        maxKeepAliveRequests="-1"
        maxThreads="1000"  
        minSpareThreads="200"  
        maxSpareThreads="300"
        minProcessors="100" 
        maxProcessors="900" 
        acceptCount="1000" 
        enableLookups="false"
        executor="tomcatThreadPool"
        maxPostSize="-1"
                
        compression="on"
        compressionMinSize="1024"
        redirectPort="443" />
```

then i tried to use `https` with self signed ssl via `keytool`:

```
<Connector 
        port="443" 
        protocol="HTTP/1.1"  
        minSpareThreads="5" 
        maxSpareThreads="75"    
        enableLookups="true" 
        disableUploadTimeout="true"      
        acceptCount="100"  
        maxThreads="200"                
        maxPostSize="-1"
        
        scheme="https" 
        secure="true"
        SSLEnabled="true"    
        clientAuth="false" 
        sslProtocol="TLS"    
        keystoreFile="/opt/test.keystore"      
        keystorePass="123456"/>
```

however, after login, my webapp always shows loading:

1. I checked the log and found that there was an exception `nullpointerexception` because `request.getParameter('key')` returns null(actually both `request.getParameterMap()` and `request.getParameterNames()` return empty), but from the browser network, this parameter has been sent.
2. sometimes there is no any error in the log, but my webapp still always shows loading.

for #1 above, when login success, `a.war` will send requests to `b.war`, `c.war` and `d.war`, the request parameters includes an `array(has 85 items and each item contains 7 fields)` and `key`.

if i remove the `array` from the request parameter, only keep the request parameter `key`, then there is no always shows loading in https.

after checked the tomcat documents, i tried to change `protocol` for https `connector`.

If i changed the `protocol` from `HTTP/1.1` to `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol`, then there is no any problem in https, and i can send the request parameter `array` too.

so i don't understand:

1. send request parameter `array(has 85 items and each item contains 7 fields)` and `key` in `https` with protocol `HTTP/1.1` sometimes will cause `request.getParameterMap()`, `request.getParameterNames()` return empty and `request.getParameter('key')` return null
2. why if i remove request parameter `array` in `https` with protocol `HTTP/1.1`, then it works fine.
3. why there is no any problem in `http` with protocol `HTTP/1.1`
4. why using `org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol` in https can solve my problems.

Comment: How do you know the parameter has been sent? Does it have any non-ascii characters in the parameter name? Are there any errors in the log file?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz i saw the parameter from the `network` of `firebug` in firefox. there is no any non-ascii characters. there is no any errors in the log file.

Comment: Do you have a `FailedRequestFilter` in the mix? Tomcat can object to various parts of a request and it may appear that the parameter doesn't exist.

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz sorry, i don't quite understand `in the mix`?

Comment: Have you configured a [FailedRequestFilter](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/config/filter.html#Failed_Request_Filter) in your web application?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz no, there is not `FailedRequestFilter` in my web app.

Comment: Might I suggest that you configure a `FailedRequestFilter` to see if that changes anything?